# Registeration using Gmail account in asp.net javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gmail

I need my website users use gmail account to register to my site. And i need to implement this using javascript. I can't user server side code for this purpose.

Is there anyone who can guide me how can i do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use OAuth 2. Google has detailed documentation about how you could register a relying party and use the [`Authorization Code Grant Profile`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1).

Google documentation for integrating a client side javascript application is available here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Go through the documentation and if you have some specific questions with the implementation don't hesitate to come back, show your progress and explain the dofficulties you have encountered.

Once you receive the access_token in the fragment portion of the url, you could query other Google services with this token. Depending on the scopes that the user granted you when he authenticated, you will be able to access different services and level of information about this user.

Comment: Thanks.. can i have some example code where this api is used?

Comment: Normally Google documentation is pretty extensive and should be more than enough to get started. Here's an article I found that illustrates some example: http://www.gethugames.in/blog/2012/04/authentication-and-authorization-for-google-apis-in-javascript-popup-window-tutorial.html

Comment: Do i need to create some kinda application on google like we do for facebook.?

Comment: Yes, you need to register a relying party. Once you do that you will have to provide a `redirect_uri` on which your relying party will be hosted and you will be provided with a client id that you will use during the authentication process. I would very strongly recommend you reading and familiarizing yourself with the OAuth 2 specification if you intend to integrate with Google.